# "Once..." in the past tense

Tags: past-tense, modal-verbs

> I was standing on the spot where the murderer had been, thinking, "Did he hesitate? *Once the trigger was pulled for the first time, there would've been no turning back."*

Can the following sentences replace the original one?

1. Once the trigger **had been** pulled for the first time, there would've been no turning back.
2. Once the trigger was pulled for the first time, there **would be** no turning back.

Which one would be more natural? Could you tell me the differences among them?

Comment: *Once it were done, there’d be no turning back.*

Answer (score 1):

Your first example could be substituted and would arguably be more appropriate. Your second example would not be appropriate to convey the intended meaning.

In the original, the *trigger pulling* action precedes the state of *no turning back*. But the original example uses the past tense for *pulled* and present perfect conditional for *turning*. No clear order is indicated.

Your first example conforms to the logic. Past perfect *pulled* is completed before present perfect conditional *turning*. And both are in the past, as is dictated by the logic of the entire paragraph.

Your second example uses simple past for *pulled* and conditional present *turning*.  But the entire series of actions and states have already occurred (the murderer *had been thinking*). The use of the present is not in keeping with the meaning of the original, even though the time relationship between *pulled* and *turning* is logical.